# Ionic - Cannot use $ionicModal inside a function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to use $ionicModal **after** an asynchronous operation. What I did is placing the following code inside a callback function that executes after an associated service performs an $http call:

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modals/profile-update.html', {
 scope: $scope
})
.then(instance => {
 vm.modal = instance;
})
```

The above code works fine when it's placed inside the controller's main block. However, in this case, I want it inside a function **openProfilePopup**. I've tried the following code but it isn't working, the modal doesn't appear and no errors are displayed in the console:

```
activate();

function activate() {
    profPopupService
        .get()
        .then(openProfilePopup, handleError);
}

function openProfilePopup(profile) {
    vm.profile = profile;

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modals/profile-update.html', {
        scope: $scope
    })
    .then(instance => {
        vm.modal = instance;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        $log.log(error);
    });
    vm.modal.show();
}
```

Here is the template code for the modal. I've used a separate controller for the modal instead of the controller associated with the code above.

```
<ion-modal-view cache-view="false">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button-icon light ion-ios-arrow-back" ng-click="dashboard.modal.hide()"></button>
    </div>
    <h1 id="page-title" class="title">Update Your Profile</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content class="profile-popup" ng-controller="ProfilePopupCtrl as pp">
    <form name="profileForm" method="POST" ng-submit="pp.update(profileForm.$valid)" novalidate>
      <!-- Not displaying here -->
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

My goal is to obtain data from the controller that initiate the modal via show() function and pass that data to the modal's controller:

```
function ProfilePopupCtrl($log, $scope) {
   const vm = this;
   vm.user = $scope.$parent.dashboard.profile;
   .......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call show method inside `.then()`

```
function openProfilePopup(profile) {
    vm.profile = profile;

    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modals/profile-update.html', {
        scope: $scope
    })
    .then(instance => {
        vm.modal = instance;
        vm.modal.show();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        $log.log(error);
    });
}
```

Or

Define the modal outside the function. Just call `show` method of the modal when function call is done.

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
  $scope.openModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };
```

Now in the function

```
function openProfilePopup(profile) {
    $scope.profile = profile;
    $scope.openModal();    
}
```

You can use controller as syntax if you want to use it like, `vm.something`

Comment: That's what did initially. I placed Show() inside openProfilePopup() which as a named function of the callback of .then().

Comment: You called inside `openProfilePopup`, but I mean call inside `.then()` of `$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl()` as shown in answer

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice .then() in your first code. The problem is that the modal's controller (ProfilePopupCtrl) is being initialized before the profPopupService complete it's $http service. And that's when I want to open the modal and initialize its controller with the data obtained from the service. If I placed show() inside the callback of $ionicModal then(), the popup will open but the controller (ProfilePopupCtrl) will have no data to work with since profPopupService is yet to provide the data through openProfilePopup.